# Pushwoosh iOS push notification with "rich HTML page" not working

Tags: html, ios, push-notification, pushwoosh

I followed Pushwoosh [ios SDK installation guide](https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/ios/native-ios-sdk-integration/) and I'm trying to send a rich html page notification.

I created a rich html page using the Pushwoosh Control Panel, selected it in the Additional data tab and added "push message" in the General tab.

The notification appeared as a regular notification with the push message as the text and when I pressed the OK button nothing happens.  According to [this page](https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/features-guides/rich-html-pages/): "Rich HTML pages are displayed in the web view, so your users stay within your app!".

My question is how to I make the rich html page appear? Do I need to add additional code in the app side to support this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer from Pushwoosh: "that's bug in Pushwoosh SDK. Will be fixed soon."

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put the below code to your start up page .i.e. index.html. Let me know if it helped.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pushNotification;

    function onDeviceReady() {
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>deviceready event received</li>');

        document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e)
        {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>backbutton event received</li>');

            if( $("#home").length > 0)
            {
                // call this to get a new token each time. don't call it to reuse existing token.
                //pushNotification.unregister(successHandler, errorHandler);
                e.preventDefault();
                navigator.app.exitApp();
            }
            else
            {
                navigator.app.backHistory();
            }
        }, false);

        try 
        { 
            pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
            if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android') {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering android</li>');
                pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {"senderID":"661780372179","ecb":"onNotificationGCM"});     // required!
            } else {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering iOS</li>');
                pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"onNotificationAPN"});    // required!
            }
        }
        catch(err) 
        { 
            txt="There was an error on this page.\n\n"; 
            txt+="Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n"; 
            alert(txt); 
        } 
    }

    // handle APNS notifications for iOS
    function onNotificationAPN(e) {
        if (e.alert) {
             $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>push-notification: ' + e.alert + '</li>');
             navigator.notification.alert(e.alert);
        }

        if (e.sound) {
            var snd = new Media(e.sound);
            snd.play();
        }

        if (e.badge) {
            pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, e.badge);
        }
    }

    // handle GCM notifications for Android
    function onNotificationGCM(e) {
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> RECEIVED:' + e.event + '</li>');

        switch( e.event )
        {
            case 'registered':
            if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
            {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>REGISTERED -> REGID:' + e.regid + "</li>");
                // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
                // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
                console.log("regID = " + e.regID);
            }
            break;

            case 'message':
                // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
                // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
                if (e.foreground)
                {
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--INLINE NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');

                    // if the notification contains a soundname, play it.
                    var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/"+e.soundname);
                    my_media.play();
                }
                else
                {   // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
                    if (e.coldstart)
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                    else
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                }

                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message + '</li>');
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + '</li>');
            break;

            case 'error':
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg + '</li>');
            break;

            default:
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is</li>');
            break;
        }
    }

    function tokenHandler (result) {
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>token: '+ result +'</li>');
        // Your iOS push server needs to know the token before it can push to this device
        // here is where you might want to send it the token for later use.
    }

    function successHandler (result) {
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>success:'+ result +'</li>');
    }

    function errorHandler (error) {
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>error:'+ error +'</li>');
    }

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, true);

 </script>
```